# Unable to open recordset

Tags: asp-classic

I have written a basic asp classic class that handles all connections to our database.
when called everything works fine the first time but the second time it is called the recordset does not open any ideas?

```
Class SQLConnection
Private Sub Class_Initialize
    set ConnectionObject = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set RecordsetObject = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
End Sub
Private Sub Class_Terminate
    Set ConnectionObject = Nothing
    Set RecordsetObject = Nothing
End Sub

Public Default Property Get Item(sString)
        On Error Resume Next
            Item = RecordsetObject(sString)
        On Error GoTo 0
If Err.Number  <> 0 then
        Item = null
    End if
End Property

Public Sub MoveNext
    If Not RecordsetObject.EOF Then RecordsetObject.MoveNext
End Sub

Public Function EOF 
    EOF = RecordsetObject.EOF
End Function

Public Sub Open(SQLStr,ConnStr)
    ConnectionObject.Open ConnStr
    RecordsetObject.Open SQLStr, ConnectionObject, 3
End Sub

Public Sub Close
    RecordsetObject.Close
    ConnectionObject.Close
End Sub

End Class


Set SQLConn = New SQLConnection
SQLConn.Open "SELECT top 10 id FROM tblProfileVillages", ConnectionString
Do While Not SQLConn.EOF
    Response.write(SQLConn("id"))
    SQLConn.MoveNext
Loop
SQLConn.Close
Set SQLConn = nothing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out if your sql statement can't be displayed in a grid then the object closes instantly like say an insert statement.

I solved this by checking if the object is open before running code with `If RecordsetObject.State = 1 then`

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is in the `Item` property, you will have to check the `err.Number` before calling `on error goto 0`.

Use it like this:

```
Public Default Property Get Item(sString)
    On Error Resume Next
    Item = RecordsetObject(sString)
    If Err.Number  <> 0 then
        Item = null
    End if
    On Error GoTo 0
End Property
```

Also I haven't seen "null" in vbScript yet. Is that a constant you made, or could it be that you are missing an error somewhere? 
The `on error goto next` business can be annoying sometimes. :)

Comment: `Null` is a keyword recognized by VBScript

Comment: Thank-you
But this did not fix the error
`on error goto next` is required sadly because `recordset` throws an error if you parse it a column name that doesn't exist and `isObject` and other built in functions like that can't handle the `recordset` object

Comment: @AnonJr: Funny I never need `null` in all those years working with VbScript, I used vbNull though. @Thomas: That's clear, but sometimes I've masked "Variable not defined" errors where I Didn't expect it.

Comment: @gpinkas - I usually use either vbNull or a null string ("") myself, but I've been aware that it existed. Nothing like multiple ways of getting the same result...